# how to access files outside of root directory and use them

Tags: php

First of all I ask for an apologize, I know this question had been asked and already been answered but I still can not figure out what to do.

I put my files outside  and before of **root directory** and want to access it when a customer **purchases** a file. I know I can use this method for downloading but I want this to get the file and let me to send it into other page and  there customer click on the link to **download** it and also mention that a customer may have purchased **many files**.

How can do the same for all files? Should I put them in a loop?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$file = 'monkey.gif';
if (file_exists($file)) 
{
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;    
    filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-  check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile($file);
    exit;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: give `file()` the path to the file

Comment: hi thanks for reply i know since in my cart there are many items how can i p access them all should i put this in a loop

Comment: you can only serve a single file at a time

Comment: Try using the path to the file, if your file is outside the root directory, you can add `../` in front of the path, in order to go out of the root directory. That would look like this then: `../rootdir/somefolder/`

Comment: so how can access many files in a time(files links for download

Comment: if it dose not matter can you say what exactly should i do?

Comment: For multiple files, as mentioned you can only serve one at a time, so provide separate links for each or zip (or otherwise archive) prior to download.

Comment: one more question my file folder is before the root directory is the proper way to access to my file folder or should i use other way thanks agian